# Pulling data from API - GET

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pull all planets names via the Star Wars API: https://swapi.dev/

Not sure where my error is in the code below?

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            planets: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/",
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let planetslist = response.data;
            this.setState({planets: planetslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error with the planets load charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Star Wars Planets</h1>
              {
                this.state.planets.map(planet => 
                    <div>
                        <p>planet.name</p>
                    </div>
                )
              }
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: For one you're not printing a variable in the `p` tag. In JSX, you denote a javascript expression by `{}`. So you would need to use `<p>{planet.name}</p>`.

Comment: **General debugging tips**: add console logs (lots of them) to make sure your data matches up with what you expect it to be. Check the developer tools and see if your request is being made successfully. **Stackoverflow tips**: Include any errors you face in the question, and include what you expect to happen what what is happening instead. That way its clearer to us what your problem is.

Comment: thanks! I have this error now: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. --------------------------------------------------- How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that api return, contains planet in `results` field. You can use:

```
let planetslist = response.data.results;
```

If you want look at working code, it can be found here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-stallman-fs012?file=/src/index.js:392-440

Comment: thanks! I have this error now: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. --------------------------------------------------- How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the "withCredentials: true" part from axios request.

Comment: ok thanks it works! could you please explain why this was wrong?

Comment: You can checkout cors policy from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. axios will add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header if you set withCredentials as true. As stated in the link:  "when responding to a credentialed request, server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding. The above example would fail if the header was wildcarded as: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *."

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://swapi.dev/api/planets/ I can see that maybe you should do something like:

```
let planetslist = response.data.results;
```

Comment: thanks! I have this error now: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. --------------------------------------------------- How can I fix this?